# Why won't my picture appear?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using a combination of jQuery and PHP to make a template for a full-width responsive picture with three sizes.  What I did worked, but I soon understood that I needed to specify specific ID's to each Div in order to have a custom image for each Div.  I suspect something is wrong with my PHP, since it worked correctly before I echoed ID's.  [Here is an example of how it SHOULD work](http://alexanderlozada.com/citycafe/) (check the header picture.)

```
HTML:
<!-- template 1 -->
<?php 
$imageregular = 'http://placekitten.com/1920/500'; //1920 x 500
$imagesmall   = 'http://placekitten.com/1280/350'; //1280 x 350
$imagemobile  = 'http://placekitten.com/630/250'; // 630 x 250
$id = 'aboutpic00';
include '../fullimage.php';
?>

<!-- template again with different ID --?

<?php 
$imageregular = 'http://placekitten.com/1920/500'; //1920 x 500
$imagesmall   = 'http://placekitten.com/1280/350'; //1280 x 350
$imagemobile  = 'http://placekitten.com/630/250'; // 630 x 250
$id = 'aboutpic01';
include '../fullimage.php';
?>
```

CSS:

```
.bg
 {
     height: 350px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    display:block;
    background-position:center;
    /* and so on for all the media widths.  The CSS probably isn't important, it just establishes the background color and background position. */
 }
```

PHP template (fullimage.php referenced in HTML)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//jQuery determines the width of my browser window and executes the following conditions

    var width = $(window).width();
        if(width<=630){
             $("#<?php echo $id;?>").css("background-image", "url(<?php echo $imagemobile;?>)");

//if the width is a certain amount, jQuery will change the CSS on my specified #ID Div using the php echo $id

        }else if(width>=630 && width<1280){
             $("#<?php echo $id;?>").css("background-image", "url(<?php echo $imagesmall;?>)");
        }else if(width>1280){
             $("#<?php echo $id;?>").css("background-image", "url(<?php echo $imageregular;?>)");
        }

//The following function is a repeat of the former, but while the window is resizing. I bet I can combine the two but this fix was easier at the time. 

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if(width<=630){
             $("#<?php echo $id;?>").css("background-image", "url(<?php echo $imagemobile;?>)");
        }else if(width>=630 && width<1280){
             $("#<?php echo $id;?>").css("background-image", "url(<?php echo $imagesmall;?>)");
        }else if(width>1280){
             $("#<?php echo $id;?>").css("background-image", "url(<?php echo $imageregular;?>)");
        }
    }); 
});
</script>



<div id="#<?php echo $id;?>" class="bg"></div>  //This is the final HTML output of the PHP include that echoes out the div with the custom ID and "bg" class I specified in the CSS
```

Right now, I should be getting adorable kittens, but I'm just getting my grey background color.  Where am I going wrong?

EDIT:  My mistake was that in `<div id="#<?php echo $id;?>"` class="bg"> I included the "#" which is not supposed to be included in IDs.  I'll delete this thread shortly.

Comment: did you look at the generated JS code (e.g. 'view source') to see if your PHP values even showing up properly?

Comment: Ahhh wait I may have found the problem.  I specified a # in the ID of the <div id=""> which is probably the problem... brb

that's it.  Stupid mistake on my part, just had to delete one symbol.  Thanks for the advice, I'll probably delete this thread soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well your problem is because your div id="#aboutpic01" and in jQuery you're looking for "aboutpic01", just delete the "#" symbol from you div